# Нужна ли запятая? "И вдруг(,) в какой-то момент(,)"

Tags: пунктуация

"И вдруг, в какой-то момент, наступило просветление" - читаем предложение. Что не так с пунктуацией? Возможно, здесь не нужна ни одна запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**И вдруг в какой-то момент** ― это выражение часто встречается, просто литературный штамп какой-то. **Чаще не обособляется** в качестве неоднородных нераспространенных обстоятельств (значение неожиданности и неопределенного времени), но **авторское обособление возможно** при желании выделить второе обстоятельство:

**Примеры:**

Сядем за стол, говорим о том о сем, **и вдруг в какой-то момент** чувствуешь: что-то происходит ― это они начинают играть. [Татьяна Шмыга. Счастье мне улыбалось... (2000)] Он говорит, говорит, **и вдруг в какой-то момент** мы понимаем, что ноги его больше не касаются края башни… [В завитках раковины (2003) // «Театральная жизнь», 2003.07.28]

Потом понятные слова стали зацепляться друг за дружку, и **вдруг, в какой-то момент,** мир приобрел довольно осмысленные очертания. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]

Answer (score 2):

В принципе запятые в этом предложении не нужны. Но авторские запятые здесь могут быть, если автору захотелось выделить **в какой-то момент.** При постановке в этой фразе авторских запятых **в какой-то момент** нужно будет выделить при чтении интонационно, сделав паузы в местах постановки запятых.

Answer (score 0):

"И вдруг, в какой-то момент, наступило просветление". Ваше право выделить оборот запятыми, и будет это уточняющее обстоятельство времени. Вдруг - обстоятельство, отвечающее на вопрос КОГДА? В какой-то момент - уточняющее обстоятельство, отвечающее на вопрос КОГДА ИМЕННО? Вы вполне можете выделить его запятыми.